# C# Serialization / Deserialization between compact .net and regular .net

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I'm currently trying to solve a wierd problem. one which i cant find much information about.

**in short:**

When deserializing a xml serialzed object i get a instance of the correct object type, but i only get default values inside the object.

**the longer story:**

Serialization and deserialization happens on two different platforms.
One is the .net compact framework (for a windows mobile phone), the other is the regular .net framework.

Serializing and then deserializing on the same platform yields a correctly filled object, the problem only occurs when a serialized string is sent to the other platform.

I have also gotten test xml files from another service that will provision my service with data, these xml files deserialize correctly.

**specifics:**

The generated XML differ slightly between platforms. ( Note, these are fragments from the internal xml structure where i have identified reoccurring differences. Read: Unit is not a root node )

Client (Phone, Compact framework)

```
<Unit>
    <UnitId xmlns="">555</UnitId>
    <VehicleId xmlns="">555</VehicleId>
    <EmployeeId xmlns="">004</EmployeeId>
</Unit>
```

Server (Regular .net server)

```
<Unit xmlns="">
    <UnitId>555</UnitId>
    <VehicleId>555</VehicleId>
    <EmployeeId>004</EmployeeId>
</Unit>
```

From parent system (Unknown platform)

```
<Unit>
   <UnitId>308</UnitId>
   <VehicleId>307</VehicleId>
   <EmployeeId>ASA 500</EmployeeId>
</Unit>
```

Also, instead of setting the standard namespace (xmlns) the parent system uses a prefix in the root node, like this:

```
<amg:RequestFinishRoute xmlns:amg="http://beans.order.integration.tt.transware.se/order/trackingFinishRoute">
```

while the data we create by serializing gives:

```
<RequestFinishRoute xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://beans.order.integration.tt.transware.se/order/trackingFinishRoute">
```

I use a:

```
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer
```

Serializer to do serialization / deserialization(only supported serializer in compact framework).

The code to do this is generated by xsd2code.

**question:**

Anyone have any tips or resources about this problem?

Comment: What serializer?  I am guessing BinaryFormatter?

Comment: if it is XML, how about you try serializing on both platforms and see the difference. In my experience, it should yield same result, but again, anything can be in Compact Framework. Real solution is not to use Compact Framework :)

Comment: If you can show us a test xml between the two platforms it is likely there are some differences.

Comment: added more information in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, and im posting it here for others with the same problem.

After some experimentation with the generated classes i found that the compact framework does not like derived objects.

The schema defined a base "route" object, and a couple of specialized "route" objects.
This translated to xsd2code generating a base class "baseRoute" and specialized routes like "someRoute : baseRoute".

Removing the inheritance and copy-pasting the code from "baseRoute" into the specialized routes solved all my issues.

i also followed VinceL's ( points for you ) advice to change to an XmlTextWriter. By doing so character encoding is done automatically, this is more convenient.

Answer (score 1):

Are both platforms use the same Encoding?
My Xmls generated from handheld barcode scanner were able to read by VFP program on PC.
Anyway I prefer to use XmlTextWriter instead of XmlSerializer.

Comment: We use the exact same classes for encoding / decoding on both systems. Sadly we cant skip compact framework since this application is running on a rugged windows phone.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this once.

For me, the problem was adding the class to each project:

> namespace ProjectPC
>
> class SerializableClass1

And

> namespace ProjectMobile
>
> class SerializableClass1

I was unsuccessful deserializing from `ProjectPC` to `ProjectMobile` even though the class `SerializableClass1` was identical in both namespaces.

The solution for me was to create a single namespace and import that into each project separately:

> namespace ProjectUniversal
>
> class SerializableClass1

With that done, you will have to include this `ProjectUniversal` in each of your other projects.

For greater flexibility, I also made `ProjectUniversal` with its own static Serialize and Deserialize methods.

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: i also do this, all my generated objects reside in a shared module